# How to select parent of element than of that parent child with id/class on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to make comments section that will show on button click, but every comments section on every post have same `id`/`class`. And I try to select parent of element that is clicked than of that parent child with `id`/`class`.

```js
function ShowComments(str, item) {
  if (item.innerHTML == "") {
    console.log("Show");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        item.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getcomments.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  } else {
    item.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button style="font-size: 20px;float: right;" onclick="ShowComments(' .$row['id'].', this > 
    div.comments)">Comments</button><br>
  <div class="comments" style="font-size: 20px; float: left; border-style: solid; border-width: 
    0.5px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` values must not be repeated within a web page. To get the parent element of any element, just access the `.parentElement` property of the element you want to start from.

Comment: there is a syntax error in your snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive it by pasting `this` to the function, that way you can target the parent node of the button by using `.parentNode`

```js
function myfunction(e){
  console.log(e.parentNode.classList.value)
}
```

```html
  <div class="myclass">
  <button onclick="myfunction(this)">button</button>
  </div>
```